# Maximizing Euclidean length of $\pm 1$-combination of given vectors

Tags: optimization, vectors, computational-complexity, discrete-optimization

Suppose we have 3d vectors $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ where typically $n$ is large (100 or so). Then we want to find a sequence of $\pm$ such that $|\pm v_1 \pm v_2 \pm \dots \pm v_n|$ is maximal. Note that it suffices to maximize $|v_1 \pm \dots \pm v_n|$. Clearly, we can try all combinations of $\pm$ and pick the one that gives the largest resultant vector, but trying all combinations takes $2^{n-1}$ attempts.

I have thought about decomposing each vector with respect to a basis ($x,y,z$ directions, for instance) but this doesn't make it any easier. To see why, take any basis $A, B, C$, then let $v_i = a_iA+b_iB+c_iC$ and see we need to maximize $|a_1 \pm \dots \pm a_n| + |b_1 \pm \dots \pm b_n| + |c_1 \pm \dots \pm c_n|$. The problem is the $\pm$ are not really independent, for example if we pick $a_1 + a_2$ then we must also have $b_1 + b_2$ and $c_1 + c_2$.

Edit:
deleted due to incorrectness

Comment: I think you only have to consider partitions of the set of vectors that can be expressed by splitting R^3 in two with a plane.

Comment: I just tried this and the result may depend on the plane chosen. I picked a plane through the origin not containing any of the vectors, and then picked a second plane through the origin by negating the first plane's normal x coordinate, and I got different results.

Comment: yes, but the point is that you don't have to check all of the partitions, just the ones which can be expressed as falling on one side of some plane or the other. I have no idea how to produce those partitions or I would write it up as an answer.

Comment: Oh I see now. I will give it some thought. I have observed that many planes can give the same length of resultant vector.

Comment: Euclidean. I am under the impression Euclidean norm is assumed unless stated otherwise. I am a technical guy, not a researcher.

Answer (score 1):

Given a $3 \times n$ matrix $\rm V$, we would like to find

$$\bar {\mathrm x} := \arg \max_{\mathrm x \in \{\pm 1\}^n} \| \mathrm V \mathrm x \|_2^2 = \arg \max_{\mathrm x \in \{\pm 1\}^n} \mathrm x^\top \mathrm V^\top \mathrm V \,\mathrm x = \arg \max_{\mathrm x \in \{\pm 1\}^n} \mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm V^\top \mathrm V \,\mathrm x \mathrm x^\top \right)$$

Note that rank-$1$ matrix $\mathrm x \mathrm x^\top$ is symmetric, positive semidefinite and has $1$'s on its main diagonal. Relaxing the rank-$1$-ness, we have the following semidefinite program (SDP) in matrix $\mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_n$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \langle \mathrm V^\top \mathrm V , \mathrm X \rangle\\ \text{subject to} & x_{ii} = 1\qquad \forall i \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}\\ & \mathrm X \succeq \mathrm O_n\end{array}$$

If $\rm V$ is such that the solution of the SDP above is rank-$1$, then we have solved the original problem.

Comment: what is the computational complexity of such a thing?

Comment: Polynomial. But it only works when the stars align.